# ASP.net NHibernate No Persister Found

Tags: asp.net, .net, nhibernate, asp.net-4.0

I have created an ASP.net 4.0 project and I wanted to use NHibernate to connect to my MySQL database located on my localhost. But since this was new for me I followed a guide ([link](http://www.makecodingeasy.com/?p=45))

The most solutions require to embed the xml file but I don't know how to do it in an ASP project.

And I did all the stuff described there, also downloaded the project but now I have the following error:

```
No Persister for: MediaCatalog.Model.Movie
```

The error occurs in this line:

```
ISession.SaveOrUpdate(movie);
```

Stacktrace:

> at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName)
>      at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName, Object obj)
>      at NHibernate.Engine.ForeignKeys.IsTransient(String entityName, Object entity, Nullable`1 assumed, ISessionImplementor session)
>      at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.GetEntityState(Object entity, String entityName, EntityEntry entry, ISessionImplementor source)
>      at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
>      at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
>      at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
>      at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.SaveOrUpdate(Object obj)
>      at MediaCatalog.DAO.MovieDAO.create(Movie movie) in c:\Users\Anthony\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\MediaCatalog\App_Code\DAO\MovieDAO.cs:line 74
>      at MediaCatalog.BLL.MovieService.getMoviesFromDirectory(String directory) in c:\Users\Anthony\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\MediaCatalog\App_Code\BLL\MovieService.cs:line 35
>      at Default2.btnScanMovies_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Anthony\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\MediaCatalog\Settings.aspx.cs:line 25
>      at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>      at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>      at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Some codefragments that might help:

**Web.config:**

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost;Database=mediacatalog;uid=admin;pwd=admin;</property>
      <property name="current_session_context_class">web</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

**Movie.hbm.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="MediaCatalog"
                   namespace="MediaCatalog.Model">
  <class name="MediaCatalog.Model.Movie, MediaCatalog" table="movie" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id" Column="ID">
      <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Title" Column="Title"/>
    <property name="Year" Column="Year"/>
    <property name="Size" Column="Size"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Movie.cs class**

```
namespace MediaCatalog.Model
{
    public class Movie
    {
        int Id;
        string Title;
        string Year;
        string Size;

        public Movie(String _title, string _year, string _size)
        {
            Title = _title;
            Year = _year;
            Size = _size;
        }

        #region Getters & Setters
        //GETTERS & SETTERS
        public int getId()
        {
            return Id;
        }

        public void setId(int _id)
        {
            this.Id = _id;
        }

        public String getTitle()
        {
            return Title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title)
        {
            this.Title = title;
        }

        public String getYear()
        {
            return Year;
        }

        public void setYear(String year)
        {
            this.Year = year;
        }

        public String getSize()
        {
            return Size;
        }

        public void setSize(string size)
        {
            this.Size = size;
        }
        # endregion
    }
}
```

**MovieDAO.cs class**

```
namespace MediaCatalog.DAO
{
    public class MovieDAO : IMovieDAO
    {
        //private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
        //private Configuration _configuration;
        protected ISession _ISession;
        private Dictionary<string, FetchMode> _fetchModeMap = new Dictionary<string, FetchMode>();

        #region Properties
        public System.Type Type
        {
            get { return typeof(Movie); }
        }

        public ISession ISession
        {
            get { return _ISession; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public MovieDAO(ISession session)
        {
            this._ISession = session;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Misc Methods
        public void SetFetchMode(string associationPath, FetchMode mode)
        {
            if (!_fetchModeMap.ContainsKey(associationPath))
            {
                _fetchModeMap.Add(associationPath, mode);
            }
        }

        public ICriteria CreateCriteria()
        {
            ICriteria criteria = ISession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Movie));

            foreach (var pair in _fetchModeMap)
            {
                criteria = criteria.SetFetchMode(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
            return criteria;
        }
        #endregion

        public void create(Movie movie)
        {
            //NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
            //config.AddAssembly("MediaCatalog");
            //_sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();

            //using (ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            //{
            //    using (session.BeginTransaction())
            //    {
            //        session.SaveOrUpdate(movie);
            //        session.Transaction.Commit();
            //        session.Close();
            //    }
            //}
            ISession.SaveOrUpdate(movie);
        }
    }
}
```

**DataAccessFactory.cs class**

```
namespace MediaCatalog.Factories
{
    public class DataAccessFactory
    {
        public static IMovieDAO LoadMovieDAO()
        {
            ISession session = ISessionManager.Instance.CreateISession();
            return new MovieDAO(session);
        }
    }
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You should check out Castle ActiveRecord - It makes working with NHibernate *so* much easier..

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell NHibernate which classes or which assembly these classes are defined in to map. You can do that with:

```
<mapping assembly="MediaCatalog" />
```

Put this inside the  in your Web.Config and make sure your *.hbm.xml files are set to build as embedded resource.

Comment: Also, make sure your POCOs have a parameter-less constructor defined. NHibernate needs them!

Comment: How do I set my *.hbm.xml files to embedded resource ? Don't see the option in properties of that file ?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio you should see it in the properties of that file. In your Solution Explorer, right-click your .hbm.xml file and click Properties. You should find it under "Advanced", in the "Build Action" property. Also, don't forget to define all your public properties and methods in your POCOs as virtual, so that you can make use of lazy-loading!

Comment: In my Solution Explorer when I click on the file the following is shown in Properties: Movie.hbm.xml Web File Properties and then only the properties: Custom Tool, File Name and Full Path. Am I missing something here ? .hbm.xml files are under App_Code folder, is this ok ?

Comment: I think you should take them out of the App_Code folder and give it a try, as App_Code has a very specific defined behavior (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23(v=vs.80).aspx). I'm not sure I can be of any help if things still don't work after that, though.

Comment: Could it be that I need to create another project for this ? I don't have a clue about this :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6744/discussion-between-marcelo-zabani-and-darkownage)